# JavaScript: getElementById получить NodeList

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как используя getElementById получить NodeList?
По умолчанию, возвращается HTML с дочерними элементами. например

HTML:

```
<div id="text">
    <p>text</p>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
el = document.getElementById('text');   
console.log(el)
```

Однако, если использовать jQuery `console.log($(el))` - то получается NodeList. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добиться такого же результата на классическом JavaScript.

Спасибо!

Comment: getElementById - возвращает ссылку на единственный `Element`. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: @Sublihim, А как получить NodeList? Есть функцияe el.childNodes, но она вернет все дочерние ноды

Comment: Смотрите ответы ниже

Comment: ... но ведь jQuery на самом деле возвращает объект jQuery, то есть сам себя в прототипе, а не NodeList ... `console.log(el instanceof jQuery, el instanceof NodeList); //true, false`

Comment: На JQuery написана обвёртка над getElementByI‌​d, которая скорее всего создаёт Nodelist при вызове getElementByI‌​d. 1.Вы можете *написать* похожую *самому* - читать классы в JS. 2. Вы можете *посмотреть как это реализовано* в JQuery и даже пройтись по функции JQuery дебаггером.

Comment: Вы можете конечно подменить window и document на свои proxy-классы, даже вмешатся и изменить функцию getElementById на свою - но если она начнёт таки возвращать NodeList, то любая готовая библиотека перестанет работать. Вы можете написать похожее на `$()` - что тоже есть функция, имя которой **$**. NodeList возвращает функция querySelectorAll и getElementsByName

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Говоря, что [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) возвращает HTML - вы ошибаетесь. Этот метод возвращает экземпляр класса [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element).

Убедится в этом довольно просто. Вот такой код:

```
var el = document.getElementById('text');   
console.log(el instanceof Element);
```

выведет в консоль `true` ([пруф](https://jsfiddle.net/oLg8vn9n/)).

Что же касается [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList), то `document.getElementById` **ни в коем случае** не должен возвращать экземпляр этого класса, поскольку, согласно стандарту, аттрибут `id` должен быть уникален в пределах документа.

Поведение jQuery здесь можно объяснить соображениями единообразия: оборачивая какой-либо элемент (`Element`) вы получаете коллекцию узлов, содержащую ровно один элемент.

---

Если вам все же нужен экземпляр `NodeList`, при этом вы не хотите использовать jQuery, то можно воспользоваться методом [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('#text');   
console.log(el instanceof NodeList);
```

[Рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/ebhsd0nm/) на JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте метод document.querySelectorAll.Пример:

`List = document.querySelectorAll("selector");`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но нужно получить NodeList через getElementById

Comment: @Pavel, все, что вы можете получить через `getElementById` - это экземпляр `Element`. Так уж устроен DOM API. Смиритесь.